# How to find which libc.so will `rustc --target=$TARGET` link against?

Tags: rust, libc, musl

I want to find the libc.so file that's being used in a Rust build so that I can query it with `--version`. (Some libcs expose their version information via C macros, so an alternative for them would be to use the `cc` crate in a build script. But others like musl don't.)

I *can* figure out which `libstd-*.so` file a rust binary or library will be linked against. When this `libstd.so` is linked against *the host*'s libc, then running `ldd` on it shows that `libc.so`. But when the host system is using glibc and the targeted environment is musl, this doesn't work ("Invalid ELF header"). Instead of `ldd`, I could instead use `readelf -d` or `objdump -p` on the `libstd.so`. But these only show the file*name* of the `libc.so` file it uses, not its full path. And that `libc.so` isn't at any of the directories in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. (I do know where it is on my own systems, but I'm trying to find it programmatically on arbitrary systems.)

Running `ldconfig -p` only gives me information about the libc for the host system.

It would be great if there were a rustc equivalent of gcc's and clang's `-print-file-name=libc.so`, so that I could do something like `rustc --target=$TARGET --print-file-name=libc.so`.

Other ideas about how I could get this information?

Answer (score 2):

You can [pass linker arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/advanced-linking.html) to `rustc` like so:

```
rustc -C link-args=...
```

To find out which `libc.so` is used, I believe the following command should suffice:

```
rustc -C link-args=-Wl,-t ...
```

From [man ld](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

```
  -t
  --trace
       Print the names of the input files as ld processes them. ...
```

**Update**:

This didn't work: `rustc` "eats up" the output from the linker.

I was able to get the desired output indirectly:

```
echo 'fn main() { println!("")}' | rustc -C link-args=-Wl,-Map=map.out -o foo -
grep 'libc\.so' map.out
```

```
libc.so.6                     /usr/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-f25e49a311b0f577.rlib(std-f25e49a311b0f577.std.cy8lhng1-cgu.2.rcgu.o) (setuid@@GLIBC_2.2.5)
LOAD /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
LOAD /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Hmm. `echo 'fn main() { println!("")}' | rustc -C link-args=-t -o foo --target=$TARG0 -` gives no output to stderr or stdout, though the resulting binary is linked against libc.so.6. (In fact, the body of main can be empty and it's still linked against libc.)

Comment: @dubiousjim It sounds like `rustc` is "eating up" the linker output. You may need to add a `--verbose` or similar flag.

Comment: Thanks! Here's a bit more minimized: `echo 'fn main() {}' | rustc -C link-args=-Wl,-Map=map.out -o /dev/null - && egrep '^LOAD .*/libc[-._]so' map.out`. I tried writing the map to `/dev/stdout`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, if you add a `--target` flag to the `rustc` command, the resulting map file doesn't have any `.so` files in it. Even if the explicit target is the same as one's host system. Still, I think this is some progress and I appreciate even achieving that.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. If the explicit target is the same as the host system, the `libc.so` is there in the map file. But not when the target is different, which is the case I'm seeking a solution for.

Comment: [It appears](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/40113#issuecomment-284500764) that when the host is glibc rustc can only statically link musl targets. So neither the binary nor the map points to the musl libc. The `libstd-*.so` in `.../rustlib/$TARGET/lib` directory seems to be linked against the libc, but as I said in the initial Q, the tools I'm able to use to query it don't report a full path to that libc. Somehow I need to find out what library search path rustc is using when a `--target` is specified. It's not the value that's exposed to the file being built as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: For anyone who comes here later looking to do this too, I [opened an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71564) for rustc. Discussion there tells me that rustc's `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` target doesn't use the system MUSL, but bundles its own copy/version.